# jq --raw-output still producing quotes, cannot convert values to string

Tags: jq

**I'm calling jq with -r parameter but still in the results, strings are in quotes. How can I get rid of the quotes?**

( I want everything either in quotes or without them )

```
jq -r '.[][] | [.name, .allocatedVCores, .runningContainers, .allocatedVcoreSeconds, .allocatedMemorySeconds]'

[
  "TestCase1_2a4e36be647a6abaf65c48fd1d3c8300",
  1,
  1,
  86708,
  88789601
]
[
  "TestCase2_2a6a14ec8365c4836bafd3fdbe647a00",
  239,
  239,
  3531555,
  5416951035
]
...
```

If I call `` | .join("`") ``  I get `` jq: error (at <stdin>:87): string ("`") and number (1) cannot be added ``

Ok string and number cannot be added. This makes sense. But I'm unable to convert everything to string.
I tried to convert it using `` | tostring | .join("`") `` but this doesn't work.

So I tried converting every value individualy

```
jq -r '.[][] | [ .name|tostring, .allocatedVCores|tostring, .runningContainers|tostring, .allocatedVcoreSeconds|tostring, .allocatedMemorySeconds|tostring] | join("`")'
```

but then suddenly jq won't recognize one of the keys. 
It can either filter for allocatedMemorySeconds or allocatedVCores. If I use both I'm getting.

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:87): Cannot index string with string "allocatedMemorySeconds"
```

This key exists and without converting to string it works flawlessly. I have no idea why this is happening.

**I'm trying to achieve this output**

```
`TestCase1_2a4e36be647a6abaf65c48fd1d3c8300`1`1`86708`88789601`
`TestCase2_2a6a14ec8365c4836bafd3fdbe647a00`239`239`3531555`5416951035`
```

Basically just convert some json into "csv" with backticks as delimiter.
I'm using jq version 1.5. Any idea how to achieve this ?

Input data

```
{
  "applications" : [ {
    "applicationId" : "application_1558485728047_0016",
    "name" : "TestCase1_2a4e36be647a6abaf65c48fd1d3c8300",
    "startTime" : "2020-04-08T15:49:30.886Z",
    "user" : "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
    "pool" : "root.users.yyyyyyyy",
    "state" : "RUNNING",
    "progress" : 10.0,
    "attributes" : { },
    "applicationTags" : [ "" ],
    "allocatedMemorySeconds" : 88789601,
    "allocatedVcoreSeconds" : 86708,
    "allocatedMB" : 1024,
    "allocatedVCores" : 1,
    "runningContainers" : 1,
    "mr2AppInformation" : { }
  }, {
    "applicationId" : "application_1558480857247_0015",
    "name" : "TestCase2_2a6a14ec8365c4836bafd3fdbe647a00",
    "startTime" : "2020-04-08T10:43:58.924Z",
    "endTime" : "2020-04-08T15:21:32.374Z",
    "user" : "xxxxxxx",
    "pool" : "root.users.xxxxxxx",
    "state" : "FINISHED",
    "progress" : 100.0,
    "attributes" : { },
    "applicationTags" : [ "" ],
    "allocatedMemorySeconds" : 5416951035,
    "allocatedVcoreSeconds" : 3531555,
    "allocatedMB" : 366592,
    "allocatedVCores" : 239,
    "runningContainers" : 239,
    "mr2AppInformation" : { }
  } ],
  "warnings" : [ ]
}
```

Comment: [`join` supports numbers and booleans since 2015](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/commit/e17ccf229723d776c0d49341665256b855c70bda#diff-b74863ae6880e7cc09f2e3f38da9ebd5). You should really update your jq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks to remove quotes, but then you say "I want everything either in quotes or without them", and then later ask for everything backquote delimited and you provide sample output. So I'm not 100% sure precisely what you want but here goes.

First, here's everything in quotes

```
$ jq '.[][] | [.name, .allocatedVCores, .runningContainers, .allocatedVcoreSeconds, .allocatedMemorySeconds] | (..|numbers) |= tostring' /tmp/data.json

[
  "TestCase1_2a4e36be647a6abaf65c48fd1d3c8300",
  "1",
  "1",
  "86708",
  "88789601"
]
[
  "TestCase2_2a6a14ec8365c4836bafd3fdbe647a00",
  "239",
  "239",
  "3531555",
  "5416951035"
]
```

The important part is the `| (..|numbers) |= tostring` bit at the end. It recursively finds all numbers and converts them to strings.

Now, to get the output with backquotes, try this beast

```
$ jq -r '.[][] | [.name, .allocatedVCores, .runningContainers, .allocatedVcoreSeconds, .allocatedMemorySeconds] | (..|numbers) |= tostring | reduce .[] as $i (null; (.//"") + (if . == null then $i else "`" + $i end))//"" | ("`" + . + "`")'

`TestCase1_2a4e36be647a6abaf65c48fd1d3c8300`1`1`86708`88789601`
`TestCase2_2a6a14ec8365c4836bafd3fdbe647a00`239`239`3531555`5416951035`
```

This steals the definition of `join` from the current jq, which the commenter above linked to, so you can join strings with your current version. Then at the end it wraps the whole line in backquotes; otherwise you don't get them at the beginning and the end.

Btw I tried this command with `join` on 1.5 and it worked fine:

```
$ jq -r '.[][] | [.name, .allocatedVCores, .runningContainers, .allocatedVcoreSeconds, .allocatedMemorySeconds] | (..|numbers) |= tostring | join("`") | ("`" + . + "`")'

`TestCase1_2a4e36be647a6abaf65c48fd1d3c8300`1`1`86708`88789601`
`TestCase2_2a6a14ec8365c4836bafd3fdbe647a00`239`239`3531555`5416951035`
```

However you mentioned having a problem with `join`, so I wanted to provide an option without it.

Hopefully one of these will help. Good luck!

Comment: I ended up with 
```jq -r '.[][] | [.name, .applicationId, .startTime, .endTime, .user, .pool, .state, .allocatedMemorySeconds, .allocatedVcoreSeconds ] | (..|numbers) |= tostring | join("`")'  ```Your idea of ```| (..|numbers) |= tostring``` seems working perfectly. Thank you !

Comment: @jmt Nice! Glad I could help